# How to enable GNOME classic on Fedora 16

Tags: linux, gnome, fedora

I have Fedora 16 with GNOME 3. I would like to use GNOME classic.

How can I install GNOME classic (2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BlueBubble is very good but it does mess around with some pretty core packages, and when I updated from F15 to F16 I had all sorts of trouble because of those dependencies (had to clean install).

An alternative is to use Gnome fallback experience in Fedora which is GNOME 2.32 - close-ish to classic GNOME. The main difference is you have to alt+right-click on the panels to get the former right-click functionality.

To enable you do System Settings -> System Info -> Graphics -> Forced Fallback switch On.

[I've heard talk that installing package `compiz-gnome` gives you the 'Classic GNOME with Compiz' shell to log into, but have yet to try it myself.]

Answer (score 0):

There is a repository that provides GNOME 2.32 for Fedora 15 called [BlueBubble](http://k3rnel.net/2011/06/22/bluebubble-the-fine-manual/).  It should work for Fedora 16 also.